# How to add different html meta depending on Vue routes using Vue 3

Tags: html, vuejs3, vue-router

I've been trying to work out how with not much success (I don't think i know the correct things to google) How i can have different meta for different routes (using Vue Router) of my Vue 3 application.

More specifically I have the domain http://synopsle.wtf redirecting to one route, and http://hangcliff.wtf pointing to a different route of the same  site. And What i'm trying to achieve is that when a social media etc app picks up the meta and adds it in to a post, that each of the two URLs gets their own meta information represented. At the moment I have stripped out most of the hard coded meta from the site because it would use the main page's meta which is something totally different than what is being posted.

I haven't tried much because I am not even sure it's doable, and when I try and look for meta when related to Vue Router i just find things about Vue Routers own meta Parameter.